# C - issue with linking libraries which implement the same names

Tags: c, compilation, linker

i'm trying to use **freetype-gl** and **cgml** in the same project, but they both implement names such as 'vec2', but in totally different ways (one as struct, other - as array of floats) which means that redefinitions lead to errors

i don't really want to replace all the names in one of the modules to resolve this, is there other way?

Comment: Yes, there is. One way to use two modules.

Comment: The standard c solution is to prefix symbols.  Have you checked if there is any build magic?  Don't link them in the same binary and use IPC which would be annoying.  You don't link headers, you link libraries.

Comment: @user14063792468 dlopen?

Comment: @AllanWind Different .c files should go to different .o modules. You can have `typedef's` with the same name in two different modules. And you can call a functions from one module in the other. Isn't that a basic `C` paradigm?

Comment: When you link those .o files into a single binary you get name clashes (functions, or the original type.  typedef would be for your code, but this is 3rd party libraries).

Comment: @user14063792468 correct me, if i don't understand it correctly, but, for example, we could compile separate .o file that work with a single library as some sort of proxy?
which means that all the definitions of this library will not affect the scope of main?

Answer (score 0):

## C99 not allows 2 same definitions

The C99 standard mentions this:
J.5.11 Multiple external definitions
There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

## 2 same definitions

### initializing definition

the 2 same initializing definition lead to compile error.

### tentative definition

A definition at file scope that's not initialized is considered "tentative".  Tentative definitions can be repeated.  An initializing definition removes the tentative status.

If you force to do this.
use compile option.
-Wredundant-decls
Warn if anything is declared more than once in the same scope, even in cases where
multiple declaration is valid and changes nothing.